# How to get the application name from APK which is in SD Card and not installed

Tags: android

Hello I have a set of apk in the folder of SD Card. Those APK is not installed already in the device. Now In my application I want to list all the application name
which is in that folder of SD Card. I can fetch the package name but could not find a way to get the application name. It always goes in the `NameNotFoundException`
exception.

```
public static String getLabelByPackageName(Context context,
        String packageName) {
    PackageManager packMan = null;
    try {
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                .getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
        packMan = context.getPackageManager();
        return packMan.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo).toString();
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return "Name Not Found";
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure. But give this a try: `Resources r = p.getResourcesForApplication(p.getApplicationInfo("pckgname", 0));
  int id = r.getIdentifier("pckgname:string/app_name", "pckgname", "string");
  String app_name = r.getString(id);`

Comment: @MysticMagic Not working.

Answer (score 0):

If the apk files are not installed you cannot get them using `PackageManager` , you have to handle them as any other files on your sdcard.

**Try this.**

```
 File dir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/path to folder with apk files");

//dir.listFiles() returns an array with all the files in your directory
    //loop through and get all file names in the directory


    for(File f : dir.listFiles())
            if(f.getName().contains(".apk"))
    //this is an apk file do something
```

Comment: Ok but how then I can get the app icon. ?